# Question about Big Endian vs Little Endian

Tags: binary, hex, decimal, endianness

So I was doing an online networking class at Standford and I ran into a question, the answers were provided after the quiz with an explanation yet I still do not understand it.

The problem was, consider ***16-bit 53 as 0x3500*** (from dec to hex). Was this hex value written in Little Endian or Big Endian?
My answer was Big Endian, but the correct answer was Little Endian.

In the explanation, he stated that **53** was **3x16 + 5**, so we got **0x35**.

For me, the **3** was the representation of the first byte **128:0 | 64:0 | 32:1 | 16:1**

And the **5** was the representation of the second byte **8:0 | 4:1 | 2:0 | 1:1**

And since the first byte was written first  (3 before 5) and it had greater value (most significant), shouldn't that be considered as Big Endian instead of Little Endian?

I'm sure there must be some misunderstanding somewhere that I have in my explanation, so feel free to point them out.

Answer (score 0):

> 53 in 16 bit binay is 0000000000110101
>
> 0x3500 in binary is   0011010100000000

since the least significant byte is at the lowest address, it is Little endian.
The misunderstanding here is that you are considering just half of the byte(4 bits) rather that complete byte(8 bits).